# Add Tab to a TabPane JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, fxml, tabpanel

I am trying to add a new tab with fxml.

I already add tabs to the tabPane.

```
int numTabs = tabPane.getTabs().size();
Tab tab = new Tab("Tab " + (numTabs + 1));
tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
```

But I can't load the FXML to it with

```
tabPane.getTabs().addAll((Tab)FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("tab.fxml")));`
```

Error: `javafx.fxml.LoadException:`

[image]

**tab.fxml:**

```xml
<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="105.0"
         prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="292.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
          <children>
            <Button layoutX="118.0" layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

**Edit: I've tried remove de `<TabPane>` tag but didn't work.**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
          <children>
            <Button layoutX="118.0" layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
```

**FXML main document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="319.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="testpane2.FXMLDocumentController">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="14.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
    <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="44.0" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="69.0" />
    <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="105.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="292.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
set 20, 2016 8:49:37 PM testpane2.FXMLDocumentController handleButtonAction
SEVERE: null
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/djodr/Documents/NetBeansProjects/testPane2/dist/run1904708287/testPane2.jar!/testpane2/tab.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2543)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at testpane2.FXMLDocumentController.handleButtonAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[9,129]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?TabPane&fx:id&fx
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:596)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2513)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: If everything else were correct (which is isn't), you would get a `ClassCastException`, because the root of your FXML file is a `TabPane` and you are trying to cast it to a `Tab`. So you need to make the `Tab` the root element of the FXML (remove the `TabPane`). But since you are getting a `LoadException`, it looks like something else is going wrong before you even get to do the cast. Pretty hard to know what without seeing the actual stack trace (and probably the complete FXML file).

Comment: Hey James! I made the changes submited, can you take a look please? :D

Comment: The stack trace says there is a syntax error in the tab.fxml file at line 9, position 129. It's not really possible to tell from the code you posted where that is, but you should be able to find it in your IDE easily enough. And when you remove the `<TabPane>`  element, you need to remove the `<tabs>` element too (since `tabs` is a property of `TabPane`)

Comment: And you would need to put the namespace information etc back into the root element, which would now be `<Tab>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with:

```
<Tab text="Untitled Tab">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <children>
        <Button layoutX="118.0" layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </content>
</Tab>
```

Comment: Just one more question. For each tab I'll have tha same controller to populate comboBox and make a order.

Now I'm having null pointers on the controller where I set the comboBoxes.

Comment: About the null pointer you get have a look at this question.The logic is the same (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628389/javafx-combobox-is-blank/39628627#39628627).

Comment: Actually, I was using this to add my fxml to the new tab:

tabPane.getTabs().add(((Tab) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("tab.fxml"))));

but I need to have one controller for each tab, so I'm trying to do it

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("tab.fxml"));
Tab tab = new Tab("My Nice Tab");
tab.setContent(loader.load());

Something is wrong. I will study it and maybe make a new post... Thanks guys ;)

Comment: @Djonathan Krause I recommend to not use the same controller,cause it is more complex and error prone.Use a different controller for each Tab.