# JAVAFX ComboBox is blank

Tags: java, combobox, fxml

I am very new to programming and can't seem to get past this hiccup. I would like to have a choicebox that is populated with options and that is present immediately. I have tried defining the ObservableList and then creating a ComboBox but it is empty when I actually run the code. I do not need to edit this array after it appears. Here is my code:

```
ObservableList<String> options = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    "Option 1",
    "Option 2",
    "Option 3"
);

@FXML
final ComboBox stores = new ComboBox(options);

@FXML
private Label label;
```

I have created the combobox in the FXML document using Scene Builder with FXid stores.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you decorate your javafx component with anotation, you should not initiate it. Only this is ok;

```
 @FXML ComboBox stores;
```

in the initialize method in your controller class.
add this code:

```
stores.setItems(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

> -->Your code should be like this:

```
 ObservableList<String> options = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "Option 1",
        "Option 2",
        "Option 3"
    );

    @FXML
    final ComboBox stores ;

    @FXML
    private Label label;
```

Don't try to initialize fxml components,the `FXMLLoader` will do this for you.You have first to call the `FXMLLoader` so the nodes are initialized and then here are two different solutions based on your implementation:

> Solution 1(Your class implements `Initializable`(for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065464/how-to-populate-a-list-values-to-a-combobox-in-javafx)))

```
/**
 * Called after the FXML layout is loaded.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    //Add the ObservableList to the ComboBox
    stores.setItems(options); 

}
```

> Solution 2(Add the method `initialize()` in your fxml controller,when this method is called then
>   you know that your fxml components have been initialized)

```
/**
 * Called after the FXML layout is loaded.
 */
 @FXML
 public void initialize(){

    //Add the ObservableList to the ComboBox
    stores.setItems(options); 

 }
```